# Conversion from JQuery to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to convert the following jQuery function to Javascript (to use in a Vue.js component).

```
$(".price-block a").on("click", function() {
  $(".price-block")
    .find(".dropdown-container")
    .toggleClass("is-open");
});
```

This is what I have so far (not working):

```
document.getElementsByClassname(".price-block a").addEventListener("click", displayOptions);

function displayOptions() {
  document.querySelector("price-block a").querySelectorAll('.dropdown-container').toggle('is-open');
}
```

Anyone able to help? Or is there an online converter?

Comment: querySelectorAll returns a list

Comment: I think it should return a list. The function I want to convert is from this code: ```https://codepen.io/paulkmiller/pen/jywwqa?editors=0010```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll` returns all matched elements as NodeList. It can be converted to Array using `Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector));` or any of the methods outlined in makeArray

Comment: @Quentin please link me to the previous question, I would like to go through it and the solution.

Comment: @DerekC — There's a big yellow box at the top of the page with the link in it.

Comment: @Quentin The dupe is not addressing all issues in the conversion

Comment: Recommend this - [You (Might) Don't Need jQuery](https://github.com/nefe/You-Dont-Need-jQuery)

Comment: Thanks, @Quentin! I missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I assume more than one dropdown per form.

```
[...document.querySelectorAll(".price-block a")].forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", displayOptions));

function displayOptions() {
  [...this.closest("form").querySelectorAll('.dropdown-container')].forEach(el => el.classList.toggle('is-open') );
}
```

If only one per form, then use this

```
  this.closest("form").querySelector('.dropdown-container').classList.toggle('is-open');
```

Delegated from each form:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll(".price-block")].forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", displayOptions));

function displayOptions(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === "A") { 
    [...e.currentTarget.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-container')] 
      .forEach(el => el.classList.toggle('is-open') );
  }
}
```

Comment: Downvoter, please comment!

Comment: This helps, but it only works on the first dropdown.

Comment: @DerekC see update